# Loading component view and viewmodel async using naming conventions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to create a custom component loader using naming convention *that loads an external viewmodel and view file*.

```
var namingConventionLoader = {
    getConfig: function(name, callback) {
        // 1. Viewmodels are classes corresponding to the component name.
        //    e.g., my-component maps to MyApp.MyComponentViewModel
        // 2. Templates are in elements whose ID is the component name
        //    plus '-template'.    
        var viewModelConfig = MyApp[toPascalCase(name) + 'ViewModel'],
            templateConfig = { element: name + '-template' };

        callback({ viewModel: viewModelConfig, template: templateConfig });
    }
};
```

Let's say that I load the view model constructor function and its view html string async. How to correctly supply them to the callback?

Should it be something like

```
ko.components.defaultLoader.loadTemplate(name, ajaxHtmlString, function(template){
    var theLoadedViewModel = function() {};
    callback({ viewModel: theLoadedViewModel, template: template });
});
```

?